# Indoor LEDs: Recommended Light Levels for Vegetables, Herbs, etc

Tags: vegetables, indoors, light, led

I'm growing vegetables and herbs with LED lights inside.

Where can I find a list of recommended lighting values (uMol per square foot) for a long list of plants that I might want to grow?

For instance, I've found recommendations for basil (500) and lettuce (50-100).
I don't know how much light I should have for cilantro, tarragon, mustard greens, strawberries, scallions, mint, and several other things I might want to grow.

Comment: Just so you know, the light levels the plant likes best aren't going to be the same for every breed within a species. For some fruits and vegetables, there are multiple species per type, too. Generally, the desired light levels should be pretty similar, but there are definite anomalies. So, if a particular light recommendation doesn't turn out, that could be why. Finding breeds bred for greenhouse production might give more consistent results.

Comment: You should edit and rephrase your question, since a question isn't supposed to ask for off-site resources (you could go in the chat and ask for them, however). Here, though, you could ask for a list (just not one off-site). People can link to off-site lists or mention reference material in their answers, but they should have a complete answer on-site; they should explain what the link or reference is about, and use it for a source, rather than for the compete answer. Now, a website is considered software; so, you may be on-topic on the Software Recommendations StackExchange site.

Comment: Need to know what the lighting value or power of what you've got now.  The basic rule for almost all plants is 50 watts per square foot.

Comment: I would go with the amount of light your light greediest plant on your list needs to use for all of your plants.  All vegetables, even the leafy vegetables need LOTS of light.  No such thing as too much light...your greater challenge will be the distance from the light.  So those plants needing less can be farther from the light and those that get taller dictate the level you set your lamps.  I'd figure out a system that is moveable as your plants grow.  Possibly consider stepped tiers?

Comment: I'm using metal shelves that are fixed. For instance, I cannot put a 120 watt LED light over lettuce at only 2.5 feet distance as it will burn.

Comment: "Herbs." Heh heh.

Answer (score 1):

I use LED 5000K brightness lamps for my sprouting station. I believe anywhere in the 5000-6500K is appropriate for green growth. My starters for squash, tomatillos, strawberries, etc are all very happy and growing like weeds under my lamps.